# IsAjaxRequest() is always false and partial view will not reload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have looked at every other stackoverflow post and none of them work.

This is the bit in my Browse page

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Browse", "Store",
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "this"
}))
{
    @Html.TextBox("searchString")
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}

<div id="this">
    @Html.Partial("_Listings", Model)
</div>
```

This is my bundle

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/shell").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

This is in my _Layout file

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/shell")
```

And this is the partial view that should be refreshed when I click the Search button

```
<div id="listings">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="text-right">
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h1>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <h1> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </div>
    }

</table>
</div>
```

I can't quite figure out what is going wrong. The controller is fine because the whole page refreshes with the searchString, but I can't get the div with id="this" to reload. I'm pretty sure my bundles are correct.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Browse(string searchString)
    {
        var model = storeRepo.AllProducts(searchString).Take(10);

        if (new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("IsAjax");
            return PartialView("_Listings", model);
        }

        return View("Browse", model);
    }
```

Comment: You have not included the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file, so `Ajax.BeginForm` just acts as a normal form

Comment: @StephenMuecke, he has added "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*" in his bundle. It should include the jQuery file if it is present.

Comment: @TejSoft, You would think so, but if its not updating the current page, then it can't be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke

here is my scripts folder http://i.imgur.com/81lESrT.png

Comment: @AlexHarley, Looks OK. Are you sure its actually loading in the page (use the browser tools and check the sources)? The other thing to check is if you view also includes `jquery-{version}.js` (i.e. a duplicate) which if loaded after the bundle, would wipe out the unobtrusive-ajax script

Comment: @StephenMuecke is this what you mean? http://i.imgur.com/Q6lAKvh.png or this http://i.imgur.com/rPwps75.png

Comment: @AlexHarley, The 2nd (sources tab) Under localhost, you should have a folder for `Scripts` (and for `Content`) that will list the scripts but I can't see them in you image. Are you sure the view is using the layout your referring to

Comment: @StephenMuecke are these what you mean? http://imgur.com/EqXlBG3 http://imgur.com/jjsApX1. View is definitely using the correct layout.

Comment: @StephenMuecke also added my controller action

Comment: It just needs to be `if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) { ...`

Comment: How do you know the IsAjaxRequest() is false?

Comment: @StephenMuecke have tried with both if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) and the one I currently have.

Comment: @BillRuhl because "IsAjax" is not being written to debug.

Comment: @AlexHarley, That just confirms that your scripts are not loading and you are making a normal submit

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK so how do I make sure my scripts load?

Comment: @AlexHarley, Not sure what might be causing them not to load. But perhaps just comment out the `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/shell")` in the layout (and any other scripts you may have) and add `jquery` and `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` in the view (immediately before the closing `</body>` tags) to test.

Comment: Does decorating the controller with [HttpPost] and then making the ajax call as a get request have anything to do with it? Is the if statement even being evaluated? Put a break point in the controller and see if it's getting called.

Comment: 1) Check the network request headers for the `GET /Store/Browse` request with the browser's debug tool -- it will tell you if you really are making an XMLHttpRequest. 2) You're making a GET request but your action is marked `HttpPost` so it won't execute as you are expecting in this case.